# The way to repair MS Exchange 2016 installation after failed update

Tags: email-server, windows-server-2016, windows-update, exchange-2016

When installing Exchange 2016 security update sometimes it fails to install and break MS Exchange installation.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4e60935f-0a5e-4e76-97a1-3d26dc8b469a/kb3124557-broke-exchange-2016-all-services-disabled?forum=Exch2016SD

After update - all services are disabled and even after enabling them services do not start. I fixed this problem by upgrading MS Exchange from CU8 to CU9. Now I am curious - if the same problem will appear again - how do I repair MS Exchange installation if there is no upgrade at the moment? I tried to install CU9 over itself but the NEXT button is grayed out and I can not continue the installation. I tried to go to control panel Programs and Features and click Change on MS Exchange 2016 installation but I get error: "The installation has failed. Run setup from and installation media location".
How do I repair MS Exchange 2016 installation if the next update will break it and there will be no upgrade at the moment?

Comment: Per my experience, in general, the security update will not break Exchange services, however, sometimes a few unknown factors may cause this issue(After all, it's just a small probability event). To prevent it, I'd suggest you run a full backup before installing the update, in this case, even if this problem occurs, we can also restore Exchange through backup.

Comment: If make snapshot of VM, disable network and apply security update I am not sure if the update will be successfully applied because of Active Directory unreachable. Without disabling network Exchange database might change during update and if I would want to revert snapshots - some data in databse will be lost. I Also I was told that if your Exchange becomes not bootable - there is no way to remove it from Active Directory without creating completely new Active Directory. The only way to move to another Exchange server is to remove Exchange gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Check Status:**
After a failed CU installation, there are many Exchange Server components which enter into ‘inactive’ state. Use Get-ServerComponentState command to check the status of all ‘active’ and ‘inactive’ components.

[image]

**Step 2: Restore it to Active State:**
For this, you can use the Set-ServerComponentState Command:

[image]

**Step 3: Recover Exchange Server after a Failed CU Installation:**
To recover Exchange server using /prepareAD command to reset permissions, recreate containers & security groups which has been broked due to the failed Cumulative Update installation.

drive letter :\Setup.exe /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms /PrepareAD  /OrganizationName:"yourorganizationname"
For instance,
D:\Setup.exe /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms /PrepareAD /OrganizationName:"ABC"

**Now Restart the server and check if All is fine.**

If it is not worked, you need to create a new server on a different machine and use /Mode:RecoverServer switch to recover Exchange server.
Reference to [Repair A Failed Exchange 2016 CU Installation](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/repair-failed-exchange-2016-cu-installation.php)